# GLSL optimization: Assignment with MAD

Tags: optimization, glsl

This article talks about some tips on [GLSL Optimizations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Optimizations).

> Assignment with MAD You can use a MAD instruction to set all the fields at once:

```
const vec2 constantList = vec2(1.0, 0.0); 
gl_FragColor = mycolor.xyzw * constantList.xxxy + constantList.yyyx;
```

> This does it all with one MAD operation, assuming that the building of
>   the constant is compiled directly into the executable.

If I assign in this way, which is faster? Why?

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(mycolor.xyz, 1.0);
```

Comment: Just as the article explains, it depends on the GPU's capabilities: "Newer GPUs can handle setting different parts of gl_FragColor, but older ones can't.". So I suppose your last statement could get translated to two instructions, whilst the first is a single MAD on a vec4 variant.

Comment: @PedroBoechat, thanks. How old is old? You mean my code cannot work on old GPUs? And is my code on new GPUs faster?

Comment: Although I never used it, I guess you could peek the final assembly code  using AMD's GPU Shader Analyzer (http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-shaderanalyzer/) and figure out (somehow) how it works on your target GPU :)

Comment: PS = for NVIDIA cards you might use Nsight